# Primefaces fullpage layout, layout unit edges not visible

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

Layout unit edges of their respective screen sides are not visible when using full page layout i.e. top edge of north unit, left edge of west unit, right edge of east unit and bottom edge of south unit.

Code for layout is

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
    <p:layoutUnit position="north">
        <h:outputText value="Top content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="south">
        <h:outputText value="Bottom content." />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west">
        <h:outputText value="Left content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="east">
        <h:outputText value="Right Content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:outputText value="Center Content" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

Following is the display that i am getting

[image]

I've tried to apply margin to layout units but it seems to have no affect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The borders are quite visible in your screenshot:
[image]

But if you wish, you could make them stand out more, e.g. for the north one:

```
/* add top margin only to the top level north layout unit,
so as not to add margins betweens units */
body > .ui-layout-north {
    margin-top: 4px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. Why is it that when applying margin via inline styling that nothing was happening?

Comment: That depends on what you were applying them to.

Answer (score 0):

did you try !important? 
like this:

```css
header{
margin-left 10px !important;
}
```

Like this it will override any pre coded code

Or try to set padding to 0, like:

```
padding: 0 !important;
```

Comment: @Humza can you send me your website link? Ill have a look at it.

Comment: I'm running it locally